# I am using a comet server and I want it to interact with C++

Tags: c++, http, rest, comet

I am using [persevere](http://www.persvr.org) for an application I am writing that controls remote hardwere.
Persevere is written in Java and doesn't supply an alternative API.

I am using a web-based GUI as the control panel. So far, so good.

I can get and set data using REST channels like dojo does but the problem is that I don't really know how to use REST channels. Which library should I use to do so?

Comment: Just to clarify. I am asking if curllib++ is an acceptable solution to send REST headers or should I use another library?

Comment: You need to make your question more clear. Does the Persevere server run on the remote hardware? If you are using a web-based GUI, why you need another library to send REST headers? A topology of your system would clarify things.

Comment: Persevere runs on the main server that controls the remote hardware.
The web based GUI has an interface to interact directly with Persevere.
I'm talking about dojox.data.PersevereStore.
Now the program that controls the remote hardware is written in C++ and therefor I'd like to see the best way to handle REST channels in C++.
I was also told about boost.asio.
It looks like a better option as the code is clearer.

Comment: As I understand Persevere server will be a client of the C++ program. Is it a strict requirement that those two communicate over REST channels? Couldn't you write Java code that will communicate with some other means with the C++ program (plain sockets for example)?

Comment: It is a strict requirement since comet works that way.
And java for embedded is a bad idea.
Persevere is already implemented so for now we use it.

Comment: Does both Persevere and the C++ program run in the embedded device controlling the hardware? Also, the Comet thing is between the user's browser and the Persevere server. I suppose that the C++ program must also provide server functionality to accept commands from the server. Do you want Persevere to be a bridge between the C++ program and the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use gcc as your toolchain you can embed a JVM with GCJ to run persevere inside your application. [GCJ](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) makes it easy to call C++ from Java with it's [CNI](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/papers/cni/t1.html) interface (much easier than JNI). I used that method to use [Java scripting](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/) inside our C++ application. You can even compile the persevere jar into a native library and link it to your app with GCJ.

The best reference is the [GCJ Documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/java/docs.html).
There is also a Linux Journal contains the article [Embedded Java with GCJ](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8757) that you can read.
You can also study [applications that use gcj](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/java/done.html).

Comment: Hmm nice idea and then I just interface directly with persevere?
Is it more efficient then using REST channels?
I know that you can pass 10 GB/sec if you send a internal socket.

Comment: It should be as fast as you possibly can be as it boils down to function calls. With GCJ you effectively implement your Java classes in C++ and just let persevere call them. I ended up creating wrapper C++ implementations (encapsulating C++ exception handling) that I called from the GCJ code parts, as one can not mix Java and C++ exception handling in GCJ (yet). But otherwise it was a relatively painless experience.

Comment: Since I'm running on linux G++ fits.
Do you have a running example that I can read?
Also do you have a tutorial on the toolchain needed in order to invoke GCJ and G++?